# Chrome won't complete 2 factor authentication

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, two-factor-authentication

Google recently added the user switcher to the title bar in Chrome.  I've enabled 2 factor authentication on my account, however I can no longer sign into Chrome on my Ubuntu laptop.

It shows my name with a yellow exclamation mark, when I click on the button it asks me for my email/password, it then sends me my code to my phone, where I enter the code.  However, the box just sits there showing the loading spinner - it never authenticates, nor does it ever show an error.

If I click away the box disappears and I'm back to step 1.

I've been able to get it working OK on my work PC so I can switch between my personal and work Google accounts, it's just on my laptop where it's not working.

Anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?  Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache/cookie data?

Comment: Nope, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Didn't work! :(

Comment: Is it just on Chrome that you're experiencing this problem? Have you tried it on any other browsers?

Comment: It's the feature built into Chrome itself, it's the button with your name in the browser's title bar, so other browsers are irrelevant.  2-factor works fine in websites that request it, it's  just specific to the Chrome browser on my laptop.

Comment: Ah ok. Are you running the beta version of the browser by any chance?

Comment: If you go into Chrome's settings, there's a "People" section where you can remove your account. You could also try disconnecting your account and re-connecting.

Comment: That worked! Do you want to create it as an answer and I'll mark it as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into Chrome's settings, there's a "People" section where you can remove your account. You could also try disconnecting and reconnecting your account.

Comment: Disconnecting my user, closing the browser and simply signing in fixed it!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it :)

Comment: I've no idea why I didn't think of doing that in the first place -_-

Comment: I think sometimes we just need a fresh pair of eyes to look at a problem. You were probably looking for a complex solution!