# Google Chrome 2-step verification does not "stick"

Tags: google-chrome, two-factor-authentication, google-accounts

I recently enabled 2-step authentication on my Google account.  In general, it works great.

However, for Google Chrome, I am able to successfully log in using the 2-step verification, however, after a successful login, the yellow warning sign [image: chrome login screenshot] pops up and requires me to re-login.  Often I can only reproduce it if I exit and re-open Chrome, but on occasion it just happens a few seconds after I successfully sign in (without a Chrome restart).

I did find several related questions on the [Google Chrome support forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qTYus6jxddo), and on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/877865/chrome-wont-complete-2-factor-authentication), but I've tried the solutions listed there with no luck. Solutions I've tried includes:

- Completely disconnecting my account in Chrome and re-logging on.
- App specific passwords apparently aren't accepted by Chrome.
- I do have my Chrome Cookies setting at "Allow local data to be set (recommended).
- I get the same issue logging in to Chrome from all of my devices (laptop, work desktop, and home desktop).
- I've tried with and without checking the "Don't ask for codes again on this computer" option.
- I've disabled all extensions.

For all options above, I've completely closed Chrome in most cases (verifying using Process Explorer that all chrome.exe processes have shut down before restarting).

I'm currently using Chrome version 43.0.2357.81.

After successful 2-step verification:
[image]

Immediately after restarting Chrome (or, sometimes just a few seconds later w/o a restart):
[image]

Any ideas for what I can look at to debug this?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on SU (instead of answer), but I have the same problem. I've just opened a [new issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OlzPWTjIJ0g) in the product forum, which also links to a locked issue with identical symptoms. Commenting in the product forum might receive some attention. As per my comment on the product forum, deleting the chrome user settings folder and re-adding users seemed to fix this for me. A recent change must have corrupted user profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed that [deleting and re-creating](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en) the user profile fixes this problem:

1. Exit Google Chrome completely.
2. Enter the keyboard shortcut **Windows key + E** to open Windows Explorer.
3. In the Windows Explorer window that appears enter the following in the address bar.

   - Windows XP: %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\
   - Windows Vista/ Windows 7/ Windows 8: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\
4. Locate the folder called "Default" in the directory window that opens and rename it as "Backup default." If the user you're having trouble with is not Default, substitute Profile 1, Profile 2, etc.
5. Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default"
   folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.

I suppose that a recent change corrupted some user profiles. This fix comes from [this related thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/N-6iVtyZCFo) in the Chrome Help Forum.